# Script in bash to scan a folder to move a docker file and execute it

Tags: shell-script, scripting, inotify

I'm new here and I'm on a little project currently.

I need to write a script in bash to scan a folder each time a file is dropped in it.
In second part it should move it in a new directory created with the name used by this file.

I thought to use **incron** or **watch** but I don't know if it's a good solution.
The scheme would be like this.

```
directory="/usr/share/docker-compose"
if "*.yml" exist; then
   do 
      move /usr/share/used-images
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the relationship with docker here? Please also edit your post to given an example of the file and the result.

Comment: Files dropped in the folder are Dockerfiles. I want to move dropped files in a newly created folder that wears the name of this file and execute a `Docker compose` command to build my container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use inotifywait. Example script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

watchdir="$1"

if ! [ -d "$watchdir" ]; then
    echo "Dir $watchdir doesn't exist"
    exit 1
fi

while file=$(inotifywait --format "%f" -e 'create' -e 'moved_to' "$watchdir"); do
    if [ -f "$watchdir/$file" ]; then
        tmpname=$(tempfile -d "$watchdir")
        mv "$watchdir/$file" "$tmpname"
        mkdir "$watchdir/$file"
        mv "$tmpname" "$watchdir/$file/$file"
        # YOURCOMMANDS
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you for the piece of code ;)